# Mongodb returning value without fieldname

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Pretty simple one, I have the following query and output:

```
> db.TRACKING_DATA.find({'_id': ObjectId('5463b1e3454208dd1bcfbc5c')},{'lastruntime':1, _id:0})

{ "lastruntime" : ISODate("2014-11-07T19:12:12Z") }
```

I want it to return just:

```
ISODate("2014-11-07T19:12:12Z")
```

So I can use this is an input for a cron script, I am doing all of this on the mongoshell.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mongo shell is a full-fledged javascript shell, so you can process the documents in the shell itself.

First, I recommend you to use `findOne` instead of `find`, because `findOne` returns just the raw document object and not a cursor object like `find`. You can then handle that object just like any other.

```
db.TRACKING_DATA.findOne({'_id': ObjectId('5463b1e3454208dd1bcfbc5c')}).lastruntime;
```